# How can I throttle my JS browser-based API app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, throttling

Here is my code:

```
var idsClean = [];

function id(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/);
      resolve(parsedLines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', getReleasesFromFile);

function getReleasesFromFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  if (file === undefined) return

  parseFile(file).then(idsDirty => {
    idsClean = idsDirty.filter(id => id.trim().length > 0)
    buildDocument(idsClean)
  });
}

function parseFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/)
      resolve(parsedLines)
    }
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}

async function buildDocument(idsClean) {
  const releaseData = []
  for (const id of idsClean) {
    const data = await getRelease(id)
    releaseData.push(data)
  }
  const text = releaseData.join('\n')
  saveCsv(text, 'output')
}

;(async function accessInterval( ) {
  let accessInterval = 2400;
  if(idsClean !== undefined) {
    for ( const id of idsClean ) { // Wait until one has passed since the previous request was initiated
await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, accessInterval ))
      try {
        lastRequest = new Date;
        const release = await getRelease( id );
      } catch ( err ) { // Handle request failure here,
        // Depending on the error, perhaps add another delay and retry
        // or loop up to some limit retrying on each iteration, increasing the delay each time you get a 429 error
        // At a minimum just log the skipped release id with console.log( id );
      } // end of catch
    } // end of for loop
  } // end of if statement
} )(); // end of async

function getRelease(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSVforDiscogs/0.1',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseReleaseData)
  }

  function parseReleaseData(data) {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.')
    return `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist`

    const id = data.id
    const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : []
    const title = data.title || []
    const format = data.formats[0].name || []
    const format_qty = data.formats[0].qty || []
    const format_descriptions = data.formats[0].descriptions || []
    const format_descriptions_formatted = format_descriptions.map(description => description.replace(/"/g, "\"\""))
    const label = data.labels[0].name || []
    const catno = data.labels[0].catno || []
    const identifiers = data.identifiers[0] || []
    const barcode = data.identifiers.filter((item) => item.type === 'Barcode')
    const barcode_values = barcode.map(barcode => barcode.value)
    const country = data.country || 'Unknown'
    const released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown'
    const genres = data.genres || []
    const styles = data.styles || []
    const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : []

    return [id, artists, title, label, catno, barcode_values, format, format_qty, '"' + format_descriptions_formatted + '"',
    country, released, '"' + genres + '"', '"' + styles + '"', '"' + tracklist + '"'].join(',')
  }

  function saveCsv(text, fileName) {
    const csvData = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${text}`
    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvData)
    const hiddenElement = document.createElement('a')
    hiddenElement.href = encodedUri
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank'
    hiddenElement.download = `${fileName}.csv`
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement)
    hiddenElement.click()
    hiddenElement.remove()
  }
```

It works fine for smaller files of up to 15 lines, but when I try any larger files I get errors like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAdkf.jpg)...

> GET https://api.discogs.com/releases/380504 429
>
> Access to fetch at 'https://api.discogs.com/releases/380504' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Can anyone please tell me how I can throttle it better?

The documentation of the API I'm accessing is at https://www.discogs.com/developers/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the CORS error is a symptom not a cause, I think. If you look at the picture the real problem is a [too many requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) error

Comment: @ADyson - funny how pictures make your eyes work better - I completely blew off the `429` in the quoted error. Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how the size of the file being retrieved would lead to a "Too many requests" error. Unless the server is badly configured, I'd suggest the problem is more likely to be...too many requests :-). First step is to consult the API's documentation and/or support channel to see if they have a limit on the frequency of requests or the number within a certain time period, and then secondly to set your code timeouts so that it doesn't exceed that limit. Could be tricky if you have many instances of your app using the same API key though - is that a possibility here?

Comment: I believe you are exceeding the limit set for your account. You are requesting a resource every 2.4 seconds. To validate this assumption, change that timeout to something like 10 seconds and see what the result is. I suspect the same error will occur, it will just take longer.

Comment: This: [Requests are throttled by the server by source IP to 60 per minute for authenticated requests, and 25 per minute for unauthenticated requests, with some exceptions.](https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-rate-limiting) - is instructive.

Comment: @ADyson the limit to the API is 60 per minute for authenticated requests, and 25 per minute for unauthenticated requests. That's why I set it to 2.4s because that's 25 per minute, so it shouldn't max out the limit even if my app is not authenticated. I can try a longer delay, but I'm really expecting a response at least every 2.4s.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the limit to the API is 60 per minute for authenticated requests, and 25 per minute for unauthenticated requests. That's why I set it to 2.4s because that's 25 per minute, so it shouldn't max out the limit even if my app is not authenticated. I can try a longer delay, but I'm really expecting a response at least every 2.4s.

Comment: @double-happiness - wish as hard as you might, the server determines how much is too much - that is what the HTTP status code 429 means.

Comment: @Randy Casburn - I get what you're saying, but I just tried changing the delay to 10s, and it just failed again. From what I can see it is not really leaving 10s between requests so I don't think my code is properly functional, ergo I doubt it will make any difference what I set the delay to as things stand.

Comment: It's also a moving average so I guess maybe if things are running a bit slower on the network at some point (so the server receives a request a bit later than normal) it might affect it over the next period. You're flying as close to the line as you can, so maybe cut a bit of slack and you'll be ok. The server may also count it slightly differently than you. Also the docs note that the server returns a header in each request telling how many you've got left currently, so for safety you could read it and pause your timer for a while if you get to zero

Comment: "I don't think my code is properly functional" ...so have you tried watching the requests / debugging the code to see how often they are really firing? We can potentially help you fix it but some observational data would make it easier, since we can't easily run it ourselves

Comment: @ADyson - I know how to watch then requests, but I don't know how to see how often they are firing. I don't know how to 'pause the timer for a while' either.

Comment: @ADyson - someone on another forum said "try looking into the response object in your fetch".

Comment: The Network tool in your browser's Developer Tools will show you when the events fire, and you can see from the data it records how often it happens. To pause the timer, you'd have to clear your interval in JS, and set a one-off timeout for the interval to restart later. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ADyson - I can see the events' durations in the DevTools, but not the interval between them. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/3hFJtSD.jpg As for "clear your interval in JS, and set a one-off timeout for the interval to restart later", I really have no idea how I'd do that, TBH.

Comment: The network tool will show you the start and end times if you hover over the requests in the chart. And you can get a rough idea just from the visualisations.